# How to write regular expression for phone numbers with new formats additional to US numbers?

Tags: regex, linux, unix

I'm trying to write regular pattern using grep cmd in linux to fetch the following format of phone numbers from text file.

```
1-434-555-1212
434-555-1212
(434)555-1212
555-1212
```

using the following regex

```
grep '\(\(([0-9]\{3\})\|[0-9]\{3\}\)[ -]\?\)\{2\}[0-9]\{4\} '
```

How the above regular express not scraping the 1st and last format of numbers
ie. 1-434-555-1212 and 555-1212 are not fetched by this regular expression.

kindly help me with the modifications.

Comment: What's wrong with `[-0-9()]\{8,\}`?

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/tvd1xn).

Comment: it works for me Wiktor....thank you